# css working on all but two pages

Tags: python, html, css, regex, google-app-engine

Specifically, pages using an optional regular expression. By optional, I mean PAGE_RE below.

I am creating a Wiki. If a user searches a term, and that term doesn't already exist, then the user is redirected to an edit page so they can create the new content. This only happens, however, if the user is logged in. To determine if the user is logged in, I check for a cookie. If the user isn't logged in(no cookie), then I redirect, not to the edit page, to create the new content, but to the login page, dealt with by the Login class below. The user logs in, a cookie is created, and then they are redirected to the edit page to create the content they originally searched for. In order to remember what their topic was, so I can redirect after the login, I send the topic(in the form `'/topic'`) to the Login class, where it's received as a parameter by the `get` and `post` methods. If a user just comes to the site and logs in normally, they are redirected to the home page, but in this case, because the topic has been received by `get` and `post` and is not `None`, I use the line `self.redirect('/edit/%s' % topic[1:])` below, to send them on to their original destination. The problem is, css isn't working for the two urls in below that use PAGE_RE. JsFiddler4 shows that there is a 404 involving `/login/css/wiki.css`. It suddenly clicked after some time that that url is not the url for the login page when it receives the extra 'topic' param. It is also the case with `EditPage`. How can I get css to work on these pages/urls when they are sometimes different? I didn't know what was going on for ages, then I downloaded and ran JsFiddler4 and figured it out. I am using Google App Engine, webapp2, jinja2. Any help much appreciated. Apart from those two pages, css works fine.

This code is out of order and incomplete, but I hope it's sufficient

```
PAGE_RE = r'(/?(?:[A-Za-z0-9_-]+/?)*)'
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/signup', Register),
    ('/logout', Logout),
    ('/login' + PAGE_RE, Login),
    ('/edit' + PAGE_RE, EditPage),
    ('/', Front),
    (PAGE_RE, WikiPage),
], debug=True)



class Login(Main):
    """ Validate form and validate users cookie """

    def get(self, topic):
        self.render('login.html', error={})

    def post(self, topic):

        username = self.request.get('username')
        password = self.request.get('password')

        if not username or not self.valid(user=username):
            self.login_error(user=username)
        elif not password or not self.valid(pw=password):
            self.login_error(user=username)
        elif not self.user_exists(username):
            self.render('login.html', error={'no_user':'That user does not exist'})
        else:
            self.login(username, password, topic=topic)  

    def login(self, name, pw, topic):
        user_hash = User.get_user_hash(name)    
        if self.valid_pw(name, pw, user_hash):
            self.create_secure_cookie('user_id', name)
            if topic:
                self.redirect('/edit/%s' % topic[1:])
            else:
                self.redirect('/')
        else:
            self.login_error(user=name)

    def login_error(self, user):
        self.render('login.html', username=user, error={'login': errors['login']})

    def valid_pw(self, name, pw, user_hash):
        salt = user_hash.split('|')[0]
        return user_hash == self.create_user_hash(name, pw, salt)
```

Comment: When you look in Inspector on the pages where it doesn't work, what path is it looking for the CSS file at?

Comment: interesting.. just checked and when I go straight to the login page(as normal) it looks in the right place, '/css/wiki.css'. But, when I redirect to the login page from the search page, with a topic in tow, that gets passed to the Login class, it then searches for the css file in 'login/css/wiki.css'. I currently don't know why that would happen.. Guess I have to find out when and where the 'login' part is being added to the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved this. Here's what appeared to be happening. 
This redirect was sending a parameter to the Login class above:

```
self.redirect('login/%s' % wiki_topic) #wiki_topic = something like 'topic'
```

when looking for the css for a page, what seems to happen is that the last part of the path up to the `'/'` is taken off, and replaced by the path to the css, `'/css/wiki.css'` in my case.

So I was passing 'login/topic' and just 'topic' was being replaced by the css path to give:

`'login/css/wiki.css'` instead of the correct just `'css/wiki/css'.`

To stop this from happening, I changed the line redirecting to the Login class from:

```
self.redirect('login/%s' % wiki_topic) to >> self.redirect('login%s' % wiki_topic)
```

the second version has no slash before the %s.